# How can I make a context fetch data prior to being created?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I am trying to implement a loading Page. I have two contexts that both require GET requests to load information. One is for authentication and another is for fetching the current user profile state. Both utilize a `useEffect` to fetch the data.

For example, the Profile context `useEffect` appears like this.

```
    ...
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        getProfile()
            ...
            setLoading(false);
        
    }, [])
```

My main context appears like this,

```
export const AppContextComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
    const authContext = useAuthContext();
    const profileContext = useProfileContext();

    const isLoading = authContext.loading || profileContext.loading;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div> Loading... </div>;
    }

    return (
        <AuthContextComponent>
            <ProfileContextComponent>
                { children } 
            </ProfileContextComponent>
        </AuthContextComponent>
    )
}
```

Now, the problem I am having is that both child contexts initialize their "loading" state to True, because they're initialized to True the `isLoading` on the top level context will be True. However, because I never create a context component, the `useEffect` will never be called to make the GET request and later changing the loading state to `False`.

Is it possible to call the `useEffect` on the child contexts in order to make the GET request and update the loading state to False while still not "create it" because I want to return my loading page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another component to have the loading logic and then call that component after context initialization.

```
export const LoadingComponent = React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
    const authContext = useAuthContext();
    const profileContext = useProfileContext();

    const isLoading = authContext.loading || profileContext.loading;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <div> Loading... </div>;
    }

    return children
}

export const AppContextComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <AuthContextComponent>
            <ProfileContextComponent>
                <LoadingComponent>
                    { children } 
                </LoadingComponent>
            </ProfileContextComponent>
        </AuthContextComponent>
    )
}
```

Comment: This works well for my original question, but I then realized when implementing it I need to make sure I have logged in first. Right now I am making the GET for the user profile prior to being logged in. How would you restructure this to make it so that once the user is authenticated, then make the remaining context requests? While at the same time, display the loading screen.

Comment: you should have `useEffect(() => { if(user) { ... } }, [user])` in context components where you want to make authenticated requests. `user` state is populated in `useAuthContext` when a user logged in @memelord23

Comment: hmm, I really was hoping for the type of architecture where I would first have an `AuthContextComponent` that only renders the children when logged in. This means I do not have the pull the logged in state for any future context creations as it is assumed you're successfully logged in, it would be much cleaner imo.

Comment: you also can try to move `ProfileContextComponent` into `LoadingComponent` (you can name it differently if needed) like return `<ProfileContextComponent>{children}</ProfileContextComponent>`. It can help you to initialize `ProfileContextComponent` after `AuthContextComponent` too @memelord23

Comment: Is that possible? I thought contexts passed information down, but if I have a `useProfileContext` inside my `LoadingComponent` and a `ProfileContextComponent` inside the `return`, will that function correctly?

Comment: I tried to do our second approach, but I could not find a way to do it only creating one <Loading> component. One of my fears is that if I wish to create an animated loading component in the future, could this result in it restarting once authentication has been done. I have uploaded this to my github account for a full vision if you wish to see it easily. https://github.com/Michael-Cowie/RadixFitnessFrontend/blob/master/src/molecules/Loading.tsx

Comment: @memelord23 your implementation seems correct. If you wanna build an animated loading, you can use pure Javascript or CSS to prevent re-renderings that is the best way for this case.